# How to end a pthread correctly?

Tags: c++, pthreads, destructor

I have a created an alarm in c++ that checks for a condition in a while loop. If the condition is satisfied then it would invoke a function. Now th problem that i'm facing is that when i'm exiting from this thread, that is by exiting the while loop, my program crashes.

Here is a outline of my code:

```
alarm() {
 while(1) {
  for (auto i : condition) {
   do_something....
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&flag_mutex_);
  if (condition) break;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&flag_mutex_);
 }
}
```

Now the condition is set by the destructor in parent thread.

```
~Destructor() {
 pthread_mutex_lock(&flag_mutex_);
 MLOG << "Thread is going to end!" << nl;
 is_stopped_ = true;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&flag_mutex_);
}
```

This crashes. Log is as follows:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f1b4302c7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f1b4303537a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f1b4303953c]
./test_scheduler[0x4039e4]
./test_scheduler[0x4037b0]
./test_scheduler[0x403232]
./test_scheduler[0x4033b4]
./test_scheduler[0x402dd3]
./test_scheduler[0x402984]
./test_scheduler[0x4020fd]
./test_scheduler[0x402361]
./test_scheduler[0x402564]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f1b433866ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f1b430bc41d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 08:13 6684908                            /media/midhun/SSD/ScheduleRecording/test_scheduler
00605000-00606000 r--p 00005000 08:13 6684908                            /media/midhun/SSD/ScheduleRecording/test_scheduler
00606000-00607000 rw-p 00006000 08:13 6684908                            /media/midhun/SSD/ScheduleRecording/test_scheduler
020ec000-0211e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1b3c000000-7f1b3c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b3c021000-7f1b40000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b424ab000-7f1b424ac000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b424ac000-7f1b42cac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b42cac000-7f1b42db4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10490492                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f1b42db4000-7f1b42fb3000 ---p 00108000 08:02 10490492                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f1b42fb3000-7f1b42fb4000 r--p 00107000 08:02 10490492                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f1b42fb4000-7f1b42fb5000 rw-p 00108000 08:02 10490492                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f1b42fb5000-7f1b43175000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10490422                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1b43175000-7f1b43375000 ---p 001c0000 08:02 10490422                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1b43375000-7f1b43379000 r--p 001c0000 08:02 10490422                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1b43379000-7f1b4337b000 rw-p 001c4000 08:02 10490422                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1b4337b000-7f1b4337f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b4337f000-7f1b43397000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10490568                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f1b43397000-7f1b43596000 ---p 00018000 08:02 10490568                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f1b43596000-7f1b43597000 r--p 00017000 08:02 10490568                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f1b43597000-7f1b43598000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 10490568                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f1b43598000-7f1b4359c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b4359c000-7f1b435b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10490460                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1b435b2000-7f1b437b1000 ---p 00016000 08:02 10490460                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1b437b1000-7f1b437b2000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 10490460                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1b437b2000-7f1b43924000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 12067631                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f1b43924000-7f1b43b24000 ---p 00172000 08:02 12067631                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f1b43b24000-7f1b43b2e000 r--p 00172000 08:02 12067631                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f1b43b2e000-7f1b43b30000 rw-p 0017c000 08:02 12067631                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f1b43b30000-7f1b43b34000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b43b34000-7f1b43b5a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10490394                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1b43d2a000-7f1b43d30000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b43d58000-7f1b43d59000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b43d59000-7f1b43d5a000 r--p 00025000 08:02 10490394                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1b43d5a000-7f1b43d5b000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 10490394                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1b43d5b000-7f1b43d5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc19415000-7ffc19436000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc195b9000-7ffc195bc000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc195bc000-7ffc195be000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[1]    6980 abort (core dumped)  ./test_scheduler
```

Now i thought this might be because i'm not unlocking the mutex so i updated the thread function like this.

```
alarm() {
 while(1) {
  for (auto i : condition) {
   do_something....
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&flag_mutex_);
  if (condition) {
    stop = true;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&flag_mutex_);
  if (stop)
   break;
 }
}
```

But still the program crashes. Can somebody explain to me why is this happening. Also it would be helpful if someone could explain me some nice teardown implementation in such cases.

Comment: Need a [mcve] to be sure that this is your problem, but it looks like you're letting the destructor finish before the thread does. That could be very bad. A `pthread_join` is in order in the destructor, I think, to make sure any resources you still need in the thread don't get released on destruction.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the observation. You are right. Just joining the thread will prevent it from crash. As i understand the main thread will wait for the child thread to finish, before this, parent thread was unaware of the exit of child thread so it was crashing.

Comment: It may be an idea to wrap your `pthread_mutex_(un)lock` calls in a class calling *lock* in the constructor and *unlock* in the destructor. That way you guarantee the *mutex* only stays locked while your class object is in scope.